# Creating multiple Dropdownlist from one Viewbag select list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, viewbag

In controller:

```
 DbModel db = new DbModel();
 ViewBag.SUBJECT_NO = new SelectList(db.SUBJECT, "SUBJECT_NO", "SUBJECT_NAME");
```

The default code for making DropDownList from this viewbag is:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SUBJECT_NO", String.Empty)
```

But in view I want to create three select list from this one viewbag. Such that one teacher is experienced in three subject from the subject list. But each DropDownList name will not be the default Viewbag name "SUBJECT_NO". It will be

> "SUBJECT_NO1", "SUBJECT_NO2" , "SUBJECT_NO3".

and in DbModel the teacher class will have three column with these names. I don't want to create so many viewbag against one DbModel table. There will be 5 different options for subject in this view and action. And for that I have to create 5*3=15 viwbag for 5 DbModel classes. I want to this with only 5 Viewbags.

I will really appreciate him who can help me.

Comment: I would recommend you not to use ViewBag for that purpose. I mean what is wrong with Strong Typing, when you need such a dropdown that you already know yo may be using over and over, then it would be better to make a data model for each of them and them loading them when required directly from razor. It's only a cleaner approach.

Comment: Ok, I will try. but see some one has down-voted my question. I don't know why!

Comment: I haven't down voted your question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Html.DropDownList()` has 8 overrides. You just need to find the one that allows you to define the source.

Like

```
@Html.DropDownList("SUBJECT_NO1", (SelectList)ViewBag.SUBJECT_NO, string.Empty, null)
@Html.DropDownList("SUBJECT_NO2", (SelectList)ViewBag.SUBJECT_NO, string.Empty, null)
@Html.DropDownList("SUBJECT_NO3", (SelectList)ViewBag.SUBJECT_NO, string.Empty, null)
```

This happens to use the method

```
public static MvcHtmlString DropDownList(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
    string name, 
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, 
    string optionLabel, 
    object htmlAttributes
);
```

Comment: thanks.. you made my day.. but please notice that some one has down voted my question.